# CameraXSource camera control (Android ML Kit)

Tags: android, camera

Has anybody in the whole wide world used Google ML Kit CameraXSource class (except me)?

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/vision/camera/CameraXSource

It packs a lot of stuff under the hood, most notably CameraX, and sends camera frames to the supplied ML Kit detector. It seems to be the easiest way to use ML Kit vision, absolutely no hassle with the camera, just initialize it with a detector and a preview, and retrieve detection results in a callback.

I've coded a demo that uses CameraXSource and most of the detectors:
https://github.com/dslamnig/Recogo

But, as it often happens with predigested stuff, it makes life so much easier until you want to do something it doesn't support. In my case it's camera control, notably zoom (scale).

If I had a Camera instance I could get CameraControl and then do setLinearZoom() or setZoomRatio(). However CameraXSource doesn't expose the camera it uses. I've tried to get CameraControl from the PreviewView passed to CameraXSource, via getCameraController(), no luck.

So, any ideas?

In my demo I've implemented zoom by scaling the graphics layer in Compose, but that's not the same thing. I want to "really" zoom the camera preview, so just the zoomed part gets processed by the detectors.

If anybody from Google is reading this - please allow camera control in CameraXSource. It's already somewhere in there, just make it public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one posible solution is to roll your own ;)

I've coded a plug-in replacement for CameraXSource that exposes the Camera:

https://github.com/dslamnig/Recogo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/slamnig/recog/camera/CameraXSourceX.kt

The Kotlin code is all mine, although I have to confess to peeking at decompiled CameraXSource.java and associated classes. The usage (including camera zoom) can be seen in:

https://github.com/dslamnig/Recogo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/slamnig/recog/recog/BaseLiveRecog.kt